# How to define score of popularity for list of tags in R?

Tags: r, scoring

There is a dataset where each object has a list of tags of categories comma separated. I would like to have aggregated categories score per object based on categories' popularities. I can define the sum, min, and max of popularities but it's not clear to me how an aggregated score can be calculated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)

# 1. Data
df <- tribble(
  ~object, ~category,
  1, "Software, Model, Cloud",
  2, "Model",
  3, "Cloud, Software",
  4, "Train, Test, Model",
  5, "Test, Model"
)

# 2. List of categories
list_category <- trimws(unlist(str_split(df$category, ",")))

# 3. Categories popularity
data.frame(category = list_category) %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  summarise(n_count = n()) %>% 
  arrange(-n_count) %>% 
  ungroup()

# 4. Outcome with undefined 'score_category' feature that I'd like to know how to score
tribble(
  ~object, ~sum_category, ~min_category, ~max_category, ~score_category,
  1, sum(c(2, 4, 2)), min(c(2, 4, 2)), max(c(2, 4, 2)), NA,
  2, sum(c(4)), min(c(4)), max(c(4)), NA,
  3, sum(c(2, 2)), min(c(2, 2)), max(c(2, 2)), NA,
  4, sum(c(1, 2, 4)), min(c(1, 2, 4)), max(c(1, 2, 4)), NA,
  5, sum(c(2, 4)), min(c(2, 4)), max(c(2, 4)), NA
)
```

Any ideas and code are welcome!

Comment: Please use appropriate tags, there is no python involved here

Comment: is score supposed to be the sum of the frequency with which the categories occur in the overall list for the categories associated with that object?

Comment: This is not clear for me as well. I need to define "normalized" in some way score of popularity per object. The sum, min, and max metrics are simple to calculate. But how to define "normalized" score is not so clear here.